# How to put button next to input Twitter Bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

How to place a button next to an input in Bootstrap. If I put some css or play with the bootstrap classes randomly I know I get this to work but I want to know a good way to do this. I don't want to merge the button to the text field like input-group-btn do. I want the normal bootstrap style for buttons.

```
<div>
    <input class="form-control" /> <button class="btn btn-primary">enter</button>
</div>
```

I get this:

```
|input                    | //occupies the full width
(button) //button comes to bottom
```

What I want:

```
|input                   | (button) //same "line".
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Option 1** - `form-inline` class...

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <input class="form-control">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">enter</button>
</div>
```

Also, you can use `mr-1` (margin-right) to add a small margin between the input and the button: https://www.codeply.com/go/5XCUJIEvua

**Option 2** - `table-cell` class...

Another option (if you want the input and button to be full width) is to use `d-table-cell` class..

```
<div class="d-table-cell w-100">
    <input class="form-control">
</div>
 <div class="d-table-cell align-middle">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">enter</button>
</div>
```

**Option 3** - `d-flex` class...

Finally, the easiest way may be to simply use d-flex which sets `display:flex`

```
<div class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control mr-1">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">enter</button>
</div>
```

**Demo** of all 3 options:
https://www.codeply.com/go/5XCUJIEvua

Answer (score 8):

Use [input-groups](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/):

```css
body {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button">Go!</button>
  </span>
</div>
```